# Minimum and maximum value of z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a div in my HTML page. I am showing this div based on some condition, but the div is displaying behind the HTML element where I pointed the mouse cursor.

I have tried all values for z-index from 0 - 999999. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Is there any minimum or maximum value of Z-INDEX property of CSS?

```css
.divClass {
     position: absolute; 
     left: 25px; 
     top: 25px; 
     width: 320px;
     height: 300px; 
     z-index: 1000; 
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkProgram" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
         <div class="divClass">
           Some Data
         </div>
     </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

I am showing and hiding the div with `.divClass` onclick via the `<asp:hyperlink>` using jQuery.

Comment: The issue probably isn't to do with z-index specifically. Can you give some example HTML and CSS that illustrates the behaviour? What browsers are you experiencing this in?

Comment: Just out of interest could you try the same thing out without using the table, just some content, the link and the div. Also put a background colour on the div just to be certain while you're developing.

Comment: "tried all value for Z-INDEX property from 0 - 999999". I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @Krumia I don't, He could try all the z-index values between 0-999999 with JS... Just an option...

Comment: No one actually mentioned the `display: none` in his CSS?

Comment: @MarkBaijens No one mentioned it because the question said it was shown on click of the anchor element via jQuery. But since 3 other users missed that along with you, I've edited it out of the question to avoid any future confusion.

Answer (score 357):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index

> **'z-index'**
>
> *Value*:      auto | <integer> | inherit

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#numbers

> Some value types may have integer
>   values (denoted by <integer>) or
>   real number values (denoted by
>   <number>). Real numbers and
>   integers are specified in decimal
>   notation only. An <integer>
>   consists of one or more digits "0" to
>   "9". A <number> can either be an
>   <integer>, or it can be zero or
>   more digits followed by a dot (.)
>   followed by one or more digits. Both
>   integers and real numbers may be
>   preceded by a "-" or "+" to indicate
>   the sign. -0 is equivalent to 0 and is
>   not a negative number.
>
> Note that many properties that allow
>   an integer or real number as a value
>   actually restrict the value to some
>   range, often to a non-negative value.

So basically there are no limitations for z-index value in the CSS standard, but I guess most browsers limit it to signed 32-bit values (−2147483648 to +2147483647) in practice (64 would be a little off the top, and it doesn't make sense to use anything less than 32 bits these days)

Comment: It's important to note that the max z-index value on Safari 3 was 16777271. This was raised to the 32-bit standard in Safari 4 so it's only a concern if you're targeting older browsers.

Also, even in Safari 3 anything above 16777271 gets capped at that, so unless you're using absurdly large z-index values to order multiple elements you shouldn't have a problem (i.e. setting one element to a z-index value of 2147483647 will ensure that element stays at the very top in any browser, unless it's competing with another element that also has a z-index > 16777271).

Comment: @DoktorJ Does anyone know why it's 16777271? It seems bizarre that it is 56 more than the limit of a 24-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: @Jools [according to webkit dev Eric Seidel](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2009-May/007708.html), that was the result of using a 24-bit bitfield - `log base 2 (lg) = lg(16777271)`

Comment: @Janosch Sorry, I don't understand. lg(16777271) is greater than 24. I would have thought that a 24-bit bitfield wasn't big enough.

Comment: @Janosch, 2^24 = `16777216`. `16777271` will thus require 25 bits.

Comment: For modern browsers that support `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` you might just use that - either statically (currently 9007199254740991) or via CSS-in-JS. If it doesn't exist you could fall back to either 16777271 (Safari 3) as @DoktorJ noted or +2147483647 as Tamas noted in this answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Answer (score 184):

My tests show that `z-index: 2147483647` is the maximum value, tested on FF 3.0.1 for OS X.
I discovered a integer overflow bug: if you type `z-index: 2147483648` (which is 2147483647 + 1) the element just goes behind all other elements. At least the browser doesn't crash.

And the lesson to learn is that you should beware of entering too large values for the `z-index` property because they wrap around.

Comment: Because this (2147483647) is the largest positive value of a signed integer on a 32 bit operating systems...

Comment: I don't think the number will *wrap around* if the value is over 2147483647... I think it's more likely that browsers will just treat any number over this value as a constant value, e.g. 0.

Comment: Maybe your value just become negative... For example -2147483647

Comment: In modern browsers going over 2147483648 does not move the elements behind other elements

Answer (score 30):

Out of experience, I think the correct maximum `z-index` is 2147483647.

Comment: Seems like you are wrong. According the tests made in 2009 by Eric Poidokas, the max z-index value (without risk of dropping elements on overflow) is 2147483647.

Answer (score 25):

It's the maximum value of a 32 bits integer: 2147483647

Also see the docs: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#z-index
(Negative numbers are allowed)

Answer (score 23):

Conclusion Maximum z-index value is 2,147,483,647 and more than this convert to 2,147,483,647

| ‌Browser | Maximum | More Than Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome >= 29 | 2,147,483,647 | 2,147,483,647 |
| Opera >= 9 | 2,147,483,647 | 2,147,483,647 |
| IE >= 6 | 2,147,483,647 | 2,147,483,647 |
| Safari >= 4 | 2,147,483,647 | 2,147,483,647 |
| Safari = 3 | 16,777,271 | 16,777,271 |
| Firefox >= 4 | 2,147,483,647 | 2,147,483,647 |
| Firefox = 3 | 2,147,483,647 | 0 |
| Firefox = 2 | 2,147,483,647 | Bug: tag hidden |

All Values tested in BrowserStack.

Answer (score 21):

It depends on the browser (although the latest version of all browsers should max out at 2147483638), as does the browser's reaction when the maximum is exceeded.

Answer (score 17):

Z-Index only works for elements that have `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` applied to them. If that's not the problem we'll need to see an example page to be more helpful.

EDIT: The good doctor has already put the fullest explanation but the quick version is that the minimum is 0 because it can't be a negative number and the maximum - well, you'll never really need to go above 10 for most designs.

Comment: I've used "z-index:-1;" before to "sink" an element so it can't be clicked. It's probably not a popular solution, but it does work. :P

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but it works with position:fixed as well.

Comment: AFAIK, you can have negative integers for the z-index value.

Comment: I wonder why I specify z-index:1000, but browser told me actual z-index is auto. position does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

I have found that often if z-index isn't working its because its parent/siblings don't have a specified z-index.

So if you have:

```
<div id="1">
    <a id="2" style="z-index:2"></a>
    <div id="3" style="z-index:1"></div>
    <button id="4"></button>
</div>
```

item #3, or even #4, may be contesting #2 for the click/hover space, though if you set #1 to z-index 0, the siblings who's z-index put them in independant stacks now are in the same stack and will z-index properly.

This has a helpful and fairly humanized description: http://foohack.com/2007/10/top-5-css-mistakes/

Comment: While we're on the topic, another common problem is not having ```position: relative;``` or something like it.

Comment: Actually, just re-read the original post.  You're right, this is probably his problem.

Answer (score 5):

A user above says "well, you'll never really need to go above 10 for most designs."

Depending on your project, you may only need z-indexes 0-1, or z-indexes 0-10000. You'll often need to play in the higher digits...especially if you are working with lightbox viewers (9999 seems to be the standard and if you want to top their z-index, you'll need to exceed that!)

Answer (score 4):

There are two super easy ways to write maximal and minimal value for `z-index` using `calc()`.

#### Maximal Value

To write maximal value, do this:

```css
.my-element {
    z-index: calc(9e999);
}
```

#### Minimal Value

To write minimal value, do this:

```css
.my-element {
    z-index: calc(-9e999);
}
```

##### `calc()` Browser compatibility (`<number>` value support) table

| Browser | Minimal Version |
| --- | --- |
| Firefox | 49 |
| Safari | 7 |
| IE | 9 |
| Opera | 18 |
| Chrome | 31 |
| Edge | 12 |

Answer (score 0):

While `INT_MAX` is probably the safest bet, WebKit apparently uses doubles internally and thus allows *very large* numbers (to a certain precision). `LLONG_MAX` e.g. works fine (at least in 64-Bit Chromium and WebkitGTK), but will be rounded to 9223372036854776000.

(Although you should consider carefully whether you really, *really* need this many z indices…).

Answer (score 0):

## Do NOT use max/min value, simply try:

### 1. Organize HTML tag order

| Topic | Bad | Good |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Desc | Use `z-index` to organize stacking order | Use **original order of HTML tags** to organize stacking order |
| Screenshot | [image: a] | [image: b] |
| Online DEMO | https://jsbin.com/zanijac/edit?html,output | https://jsbin.com/gakeqix/edit?html,output |

### 2. Create new The stacking context to isolate z-index

| Topic | Bad | Good |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Desc | Use `z-index: max || min` to override the other tag | Use fixed `z-index: 0` to isolate The stacking context |
| Screenshot | [image: bad] | [image: good] |
| Online DEMO | https://jsbin.com/lavofef/edit?html,output | https://jsbin.com/qakegup/edit?html,output |

---

## You don't need z-index

z-index is dangerous:

- It is infectious:  If one tag gets z-index, more  tags will be infected in order to override the old one.
- It will inflate: If one tag gets `z-index: 1`;,  more  tags will have to use `z-index: 2;`, `z-index: 3;` ... `z-index: max || min;`, Boom!.

Use `z-index: max || min;` is especially dangerous. If one tag gets z-index: max , it will be hard to override by others, the whole project will out of control gradually.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern and proper approach would be to use this:

```css
.lowest {
  z-index: calc(-infinity);
}
```

```css
.highest {
  z-index: calc(infinity);
}
```

This is supported in all major browsers: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_calc-constant_infinity