# z-index maximum value

Tags: html, css, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mininum and Maximum value of Z-INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index)

What is the maximum value I can use for z-index? Does it depend on the browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does depend on the browser

http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index you may want to add your answer there