# jQuery UI Dialog Styling - Overflow?

Tags: jquery-ui, coding-style, dialog, styling

Hey Stack, need some assistance with the styling of jQuery UI Dialogs. You can see what is happening here: http://img714.imageshack.us/i/jquerydialogstylingissu.png/.

The Validation Message and the Icon in the top left are both being cut off. I thought it was because .ui-dialog has "overflow: hidden", but removing that has no effect (that I could see). Can anyone offer any suggestions to get these displaying correctly?

The HTML for the title bar after attaching the top left icon is:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<img style="position: absolute; left: -28px; top: -25px; z-index: 2147483647;" src="/img/browser.png">
<span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-TaskEditWindow">Task Details</span>
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
</div>
```

Edit (Thanks to Cubed Eye Studios):

Changing .ui-dialog and .ui-dialog-content to "overflow: visible" fixes this, however you will lose the auto-scroll on the content area and may get unexpected results for the title bar (Assuming there was a reason for overflow to be hidden on titles in the first place. I have not noticed anything different.). Losing the auto scroll is a big deal. Any suggestions to work around that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Additional Code:

```
<div style="display: block; z-index: 1004; outline: 0px none; height: auto; width: auto; top: 157px; left: 756px;" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all  ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-StageEditWindow">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <img style="position: absolute; left: -23px; top: -20px;" src="/img/browser.png">
        <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-StageEditWindow">Stage Details</span>
        <a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
    </div>
    <div style="width: auto; min-height: 50.8px; height: auto;" id="StageEditWindow" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
        <div class="screens-container">
            <div id="DetailsScreen">
                <form id="StageEditForm" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <fieldset id="DetailsFieldSet">
                        <div>
                            <label class="label" for="StageName">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="input required validation-failed" name="Name" id="StageName">
                            <label for="StageName" generated="true" class="validation-failed" style="position: absolute; top: -121.95px; left: 107.1px; opacity: 0; display: none;">This field is required.</label>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
            <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Save</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Tooltip Solution (only for this particular tooltip plugin)**

Change the getCropping() function in the dynamic plugin for the tooltip, so that it works on the content container rather than the window.

```
function getCropping(el) {
    var w = $(el).closest('.ui-dialog-content');
    var right = w.offset().left + w.width();
    var bottom = w.offset().top + w.height();
    var toolTipRight = el.offset().left + el.width();
    var toolTipBottom = el.offset().top + el.height();

    return [
        el.offset().top <= w.offset().top,                      // top
        right <= toolTipRight,          // right
        bottom <= toolTipBottom,        // bottom
        w.offset().left >= el.offset().left                     // left
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the icon, just make the overflow on the dialog visible.

```
<div class="ui-dialog" style="overflow:visible">
```

The Validation message looks like a z-index thing, can you post some more code?

Comment: Thanks. Changing overflow to "visible" in the CSS worked. Can you explain why removing "overflow: hidden" didn't have the same effect? Isn't the default value of overflow "visible"? Changing .ui-dialog-content to overflow: visible also stops the validation message from being cut off, but you then lose the auto scroll bar functionality. Any ideas for that?

Comment: I'm not sure why the overflow:visible needs to be set, because as you said it's default, but it looks like browsers default overflow to auto. As for the validation message, I don't think overflow is the best option, z-index would be better. Can you post some more code

Comment: I had already tried z-index for both of them (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066525/jquery-tooltips-and-dialog/4066818#4066818). Sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not overly familiar with that tooltip plugin, but I imagine that the tooltips are placed absolutely. I made this demo that seemed to work correctly, maybe you can translate it to the plugin.

```
<div class="ui-dialog" style="overflow:visible;">
   <div class="ui-dialog-title" style="position:relative; z-index:5">Title Bar</div>
   <div class="ui-dialog-content" style="position:relative; z-index:10">
      Content Here
      <div class="tooltip" style="position:absolute; top:-4px;">
           Tooltip Content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I just made sure that the z-index of the content part is bigger that the title part. Not sure if this is any help but give it a try. Also make them both relative, instead of absolute.

Comment: The issue is not with z-index. Regardless of the z-index, overflow: auto will still cut it off.