# Force element to be the topmost element on a page

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, inject

I have a Chrome extension that injects an `iframe` to a web page.
The `iframe` element has a `z-index = 2147483647`. 
There's another extension installed on my Chrome that does something similar (i.e. injects an iframe with `z-index=2147483647`).

The other extension's iframe shows ON TOP of my extension's iframe.

On Chrome (and I guess on other browsers), the last element on the page will show top-most. (again - assuming z-index is at the highest value).

I tried changing my extension name so it will invoke last (after the other extension is loaded) and therefore having my iframe injected at the end. It did not work, it seems that the other extension also wants to be the top-most.

Is there anyway to make sure my iframe will be injected right before the `</body>` tag? after any other element has been injected/loaded?

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752175/force-div-to-be-topmost-element-of-any-and-all-webpages) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index), which did not help.

I thought about setting a timer and then after all elements were loaded adding my iframe, but it seems kinda hacky, and if there's another extension that does the same, we will end up with a timers-fight :).

Comment: Why don't you change the z-index of the other elements, or is that not an option?

Comment: And to answer your question about right before </body>, you can do `$('body').append(myElement);`, assuming you have jQuery. If you don't, look for jquery append() with pure javascript. (it's pretty simple too)

Comment: I do not control the other extension z-index. I could maybe go over all elements' z-index and set them below mine, but again, it seems hacky, and maybe I will miss the other extension's z-index since it was not set yet...

Comment: @HamzaKubba - the `append()` function add the element after the `<body>` tag, it does not MAKE SURE the element is added JUST BEFORE the `</body>` tag.

Comment: No, `append()` adds the element to the end of the <body> tag, not after it. That means JUST BEFORE the </body> tag. Of course, it doesn't guarantee nothing will be added after it later, but that's another unrelated problem... you can fix that one by checking if it's the last element on a timer (using `myElement.next()`, for example).

Comment: @HamzaKubba - thanks for correcting me, yet again, it does not help, since if there's a code running after my `$('body').append(myElement` it will be added after my element. As I said - I want to guarantee my element to be the top-most - what you suggest (timer) is what I wrote on my question, is this the solution?

Comment: Ah sorry, missed the last bit of your post.. yes, I believe it's the only way to 'guarantee' it (or be as close to guaranteed as possible). Put it this way... whatever solution you come up with, no matter how good, someone else can do as well. :)

Comment: You could also be 'mean'... if the timer function that uses `.next()` finds something, you could just delete it entirely, for example, heh. This could lead to behavior that is unwanted by the user though. At the end of the day, if there's a conflict with another app, the user will have to resolve it eventually. So I'd say some reasonable effort is warranted, but don't go too crazy or your attempts will just backfire (by making your users hate you :) )

Comment: Thanks @HamzaKubba, I will see what works and update the question/answer accordingly.