# jQuery Autocomplete Inside a Popup

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement the autocomplete behaviour to my application using jQuery.
 My component for autocomplete is present inside a popup box and I am able to call the 
 autocomplete method on this component I mean I am getting the data from AJAX (verified in firebug)
 But that data is not getting displayed in UI side

Where as if I integrate to a component directly present in a page (not in popup) I am able to get the behaviour.

Hoping some CSS issue.

```
$('#id').live("keydown.autocomplete", function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                'url': 'http://localhost:7001/solr/select',
                    'dataType': 'jsonp',
                    'jsonp': 'json.wrf',
                    'data': {
                    'wt': 'json',
                        'q': "state:*" + request.term + "*"
                },
                    'success': function (data) {
                    response(
                    $.map(data.response.docs, function (item, i) {
                        return {
                            label: item.state,
                            value: item.state
                        };
                    }));
                },
                 open: function(event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("position", "absolute");
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("top", "100px");
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("left", "100px");
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", "99999999999999px");
                    }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: @user1671639 have updated my post with code

Comment: you say `Hoping some css issue.` but yet you dont provide css code

Comment: Are using `live`?? It is depreciated, so use `.on()`. For reason check [diff between on and live?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on)

Comment: @Bingo: update the code for css but z-index is not working

Comment: @user1671639 : Thanks for reminding me i will update that

Comment: @DeadMan possible to show your respective HTML code?

Comment: @user1671639 : Thanks for our help i have fixed my problem by reducing the Z-index of parent component :)

Comment: @DeadMan oh, Great :)

Comment: @DeadMan if you did fixed your problem by reducing z-index you can select any one of the answer as selected, it will help future visitors as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change this (**remove px**)

```
$(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", "99999999999999px");
```

to

```
$(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", "2147483647");
```

**FYI:**  z-index: 2147483647 is the max value. check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856569/1671639).

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` takes `number` (not appended with **px** and I strongly doubt about setting `z-index` to such a higher value `99999999999999`) as property value,

check the usage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

example: `z-index: -1;`

Answer (score 0):

Put the setting in a css file and then you don't have to type it out for every autocomplete, although you can still qualify the setting there if you need to:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 2147483647;
}
```