# HTML code causing styling error

Tags: html, css

This code:

```
<div class="social">
<span class="st_facebook_large"></span>
<span class="st_twitter_large"></span>
<span class="st_email_large"></span>
<span class="st_sharethis_large"></span>
<span class="st_plusone_button_large"></span>
</div>
```

is causing this styling error:

[image]

[URL to this scenario](http://www.shopstuff.se/produkt/nam-dehicula-eros-tempor-auctor-lorem-4/)

My question: How can I make this picture appear **IN FRONT** of the "Share this"-buttons?

Comment: Show the code for image.. And css also.. You need to set z- index for image.. Eg: z-index:3

Comment: There are hundreds of questions for z-index on SO.. Plz close..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mininum and Maximum value of Z-INDEX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index)

Comment: Add absolute position to image and positive z-index... **position: absolute; z-index: 1 !important;** . Regards.

Comment: Hi, @NaeemShaikh , I am very new to coding and would appreciate some help to this, not reading something else That I have no clue about.

Comment: @Milan Where do I add that?, regards

Comment: To image, but i see you solve the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove `z-index` from `#single-product .images > .yith_magnifier_zoom_wrap`

**OR**

Give `z-index:99;` in `#single-product .images > .yith_magnifier_zoom_wrap`

**OR**

Specify `z-index:99;` as inline-CSS for div with class name `yith_magnifier_zoom_magnifier` as usage of `!important` in CSS is not recommended..

Comment: You are awsome, you just combined 2 of the questions and gave me the right result. Cheers to you.

Comment: Yes it works! By the way what is the diffrence in giving it `z-index:99` to `z-index:999` ?Thank you .)

Comment: Basically..the z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Comment: It would be safe to use `z-index:99;` if you have less than 99 elements and if greater use a higher value instead..

Comment: Oh I understand, Thank you for the well explained answer. By the way the error appeared again, would you mind looking at it again in the [link](http://www.shopstuff.se/produkt/nam-dehicula-eros-tempor-auctor-lorem-4/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69408/discussion-between-joneskvist-and-lal).

Answer (score 1):

in the stylesheet add this:

```
.yith_magnifier_zoom_wrap {z-index:999 !important}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works!! Is there a way to do this in the CSS instead of the style sheet? since I am not using any child-theme.

Comment: I managed to solve this by the help of @Lal. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.social {
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
margin-left: -50px;
}

.image
{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
```

You may need to play with a negative margin or padding to get the buttons to not be covered by the image...

Comment: Hm when you say **play with a negative margin or padding** which components in the css are you talking about? Regards

Comment: I've updated my sample - if you use a negative margin on the left or the top, you can pull the content in that direction. This would pull the social div 50 pixels to the left.

Comment: Hi can you please edit your answer and write `z-index:999` because that one worked for me. So I can mark your answer as solved. By the way what does the z-index do? You have written to of them. One in the .social and one in the .image.

Comment: z-index treats your content like a stack of cards. Lower numbers are lower in the stack, higher numbers are higher. It's like sticking post-it notes of varying sizes on a piece of paper.