# Stacking HTML elements using z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to better understand the `CSS` `z-index` property and stacking contexts.

As practice, I've built a little `HTML` demo containing some elements, and I am trying to order them in all kinds of different orders using `z-index` positioning only.

The basic demo is available in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2773hggL/1/).

Now, is it possible to stack the elements in the above demo in the following order (farthest to closest): `#d1, #d4, #d2, #d3` ?

(To clarify, the order in the initial demo is: `#d1, #d3, #d2, #d4`)

---

### Edit:

Prior to asking this question, I have actually searched and read about `z-index` and stacking contexts. I am familiar with the general rules and specification of how `z-index` works, and when stacking contexts are created.

Hence, this is not a general "I do not understand how z-index works" question, and therefore it is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513540/understanding-z-index-stacking-order).

This question refers to the specific case that I have presented above in as much detail as I could. What I ask for is a very specific answer to that specific question - either "Yes, this can be done like so...", or "No, this can't be achieved, because..."

Comment: element with higher z-index will appear closest( on top)

Comment: @CavanPage I am familiar with the general rules. Can the specific order presented in the question be achieved using z-index positioning? If so, how? Otherwise, why not?

Comment: Yes this can be done. Ex. Set #d1 to 1, #d4 to 2, #d2 to 3, and #d3 to 4 . As long as element X has a higher z-index than element Y, element X will overlap . see this for max & min values of z-index (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index)

Comment: This doesn't work, because of the stacking contexts created by #d1 and #d2 (the parent elements of #d3 and #d4, respectively)

Comment: I see what the issue is now. Do you need to nest the elements?

Comment: @CavanPage Yes.