# Context Menu opens in weird places when scrolled down

Tags: javascript

I have a website where I have put in some custom context menus using javascript. When the page loads, everything works out fine. However, when you scroll down, the context menu opens up the number of pixels that I have scrolled below the cursor. I have included a glitch project of my problem below. Thanks in advance!

https://stripe-water-1.glitch.me/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, when you scroll down, the context menu opens up the number of
> pixels that I have scrolled below the cursor.

You can findout how many pixels you scrolled by `element.scrollTop`. Here scroll is applied to your `html`. So you need to get html.scrollTop. `html` object will be obtained by `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];`
Update your top position as below.

`menu.style.top = (top - html.scrollTop) + "px";`

You can check below complete code.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
let menuVisible = false;
let html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
const toggleMenu = command => {
  menu.style.display = command === "show" ? "block" : "none";
  menuVisible = !menuVisible;
};

const setPosition = ({ top, left }) => {
  menu.style.left = left + "px";
  menu.style.top = (top - html.scrollTop) + "px";
  toggleMenu("show");
};

window.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (menuVisible) toggleMenu("hide");
});

window.addEventListener("contextmenu", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const origin = {
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  };
  setPosition(origin);
  return false;
});
```

```css
/* CSS files add styling rules to your content */


.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 0.2s display ease-in;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu-options {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu-option a {
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
  // border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.menu-option  {
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
  // border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
}

.menu-option:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>  
  <body onclick="document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';">
    <div class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-options">

    <li class="menu-option" style="border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;"><a href="https://www.jeffthecow.com/">&#149;&nbsp; Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-option"><a href="https://www.jeffthecow.com/JeffNews/">&#149;&nbsp; News</a></li>
    <li class="menu-option"><a href="https://www.jeffthecow.com/Projects/">&#149;&nbsp; Projects</a></li>
    <li class="menu-option"><a href="https://www.jeffthecow.com/JeffGames/">&#149;&nbsp; Games</a></li>
    <li class="menu-option" style="border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;"><a href="javascript:window.print()">&#149;&nbsp; Print</a></li>
    <li class="menu-option"><a href="javascript:location.reload()">&#149;&nbsp; Reload</a></li>
    <li class="menu-option"><a href="javascript:window.history.back()">&#149;&nbsp; Back</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
      Scroll down then right click to see the issue.
    </h1>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>
      text is for scrolling...<br>         
    </p>

    <!-- include the Glitch button to show what the webpage is about and
          to make it easier for folks to view source and remix -->
    <div class="glitchButton" style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;"></div>
    <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a well-written answer that I really appreciate. I am sorry that I did not see it sooner. Thank you so much. (It has been implemented on my site as well https://www.jeffthecow.com/ )

Comment: Are you sure the menu will be on top of other items ?  
[See this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/491105/474535)  `z-index` is an `int` type

Comment: @barts, `z-index` was not the issue here. I just had copied that css code from the page mentioned in question. For simplicity I've updated my answer and used `999` instead of huge value.