# sibling stays behind, despite having highter z-index

Tags: html, css

In the following code first sibling stays behind despite having higher z-index. Why is that?

```html
   
<div style="z-index: 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000;position: fixed;">why its not in front?</div>

<div style="
    height: 110px;
    width: 60px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000000000000000000000000000000000;
"></div>
```

Comment: why use such a high z-index?

Comment: because I lke websites with higher z-index

Answer (score 2):

The `z-index` you're setting is higher than the available range. You'll need to use a value in the available range:

```html
<div style="z-index: 1;position: fixed;">why its not in front?</div>
<div style="
    height: 110px;
    width: 60px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some reference about the available limit?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index